# DynamoDB GSI empty?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, nosql, serverless

I'm doing a small serverless todo app and I created a GSI in an empty table in the dynamo GUI, the table has a `PK = id` and `SK = userId` with the GSI `PK = gsi1pk` which is a combo of the userId and todo and `SK = status`.

I've added items using my api with this schema in the code

```
 Item: {
            id: { S: uuidv4() },
            userId: { S: todo.userId },
            title: { S: todo.title },
            description: { S: todo.description },
            createdAt: { S: currentDate.toISOString() },
            status: { S: todo.status },
            entityType: { S: 'todo' },
            gsi1pk: { S: `${todo.userId}#todo` }
        }
```

with the API request being

```
{
    "userId": "emma1",
    "title": "Schedule gym session",
    "description": "Book a workout session with a personal trainer",
    "createdAt": "2023-05-26T11:45:00Z",
    "status": "pending",
    "entityType": "todo"
}
```

And my GSI is still saying my item count is zero? What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your GSI is saying your item count is 0 because you only created it, the count is only updated every 6 hours.

To do a live count, do a `Scan` with `Select=COUNT` to retrieve an accurate count.

```
aws dynamodb scan \
--table-name myTable \
--index-name myIndex \
--select COUNT
```

If you are still seeing no items, then ensure

1. That your items contain both the GSI PK and the GSI SK
2. That the attribute values match the type string/number/binary
3. That the attribute names match, casing also counts

Comment: It's there now, thank you! Is there a way to have it take less time to update?

Comment: No, you have to do a scan like I highlighted in my answer.